# Can someone correct what I did wrong with my overloading function?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I am not very familiar with the use of template and overloading, and I was asked to correct a code as a practice exercise. I corrected all that I can manage to identify, but I am not sure what did I overlook. I apologize if the variable name sounds bad to you, they all came with the original broken code.

Part of the error message is

> CSL.cpp: In member function 'void CSL::showList() [with T = int]':
>
> CSL.cpp:106:   instantiated from here CSL.cpp:26: error: subscripted
>   value is neither array nor pointer

The code itself:

```
template<class T>
CSL<T>::CSL(T *d, int s) : data(*d), size(s)
{
}

template<class T>
void CSL<T>::showList()                 //Function with problem.
{
  cout<<"Comma separated list:"<<endl;
  for(int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
  {
    cout << data[x];
    if(x != size + 1)
      cout << ": ";
  }
  cout << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{

  someCustomers[0].setCustomer("Zaps", 23.55);
  //...
  someCustomers[5].setCustomer("Curtin",56999.19);

  CSL_Size = sizeof(someInts)/sizeof(someInts[0]);
  CSL<int> CSL_Integers(someInts, CSL_Size);
  //...    
  CSL_Size = sizeof(someCustomers)/sizeof(someCustomers[0]);
  CSL<Customer> CSL_Customers(someCustomers, CSL_Size);

  CSL_Integers.showList();   //Problem starts here
  CSL_Doubles.showList();
  CSL_Videos.showList();
  CSL_Customers.showList();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you get rid of the redundant code that is not necessary to exhibit the problematic behaviour, maybe.

Comment: -1 for posting wall of code and not cutting down to a simple illustration of the problem. If you don't do that, it means more work for us. If you do that, it's less work for us, and more for you. Since it's your problem, you need to bear the bulk of the effort.

Comment: Ouch. I'll trim the code right away.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I truly do appreciate that you let me know instead of others who just mark down without addressing my mistake. Thank you once again

Comment: Downvote removed, thanks for taking the advice so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CLS` class template accepts a type parameter `T` and defines a data member `data` of that type.

When you are providing `int` as a type argument for `T`, the type of the internal data member `data` is, therefore `int`.

In your `showList()` function, you are then trying to apply the subscript operator to that `int`, passing another integral value as the input to `operator []`:

```
cout << data[x];
```

But that's illegal, since there is no pointer arithmetic involved (`data` is not array, nor a pointer, and neither is `x`). That basically amounts to doing something along these lines:

```
42[1729]
```

Which is obviously non-sense. You probably meant to have `T*` as the type of `data`, and rewrite your constructor as:

```
template<class T>
CSL<T>::CSL(T *d, int s) : data(d), size(s)
//                         ^^^^^^^
//                         Just pass d instead of *d
{
}
```

Notice, however, that leaving the ownership of the encapsulated container to clients is an awkward design decision. This way, you will have to make sure the `CSL` object won't outlive the array (otherwise, `data` will be a dangling pointer).

For this reason, your `CLS` class should contain a *copy* of the array provided as the input to the constructor. And in order to avoid making mistakes with dynamic allocation, deletion of the array, the Rule of Three, the Rule of Five and whatnot, you should be using RAII wrappers such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. 100% understood what I did wrong now! Thank you once again!